# Select * from table where column.id is not in the other table's column1 OR column2? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a **Users** table:

```
 id |   username   |          email          
----+--------------+-------------------------
  6 | grahamsutt12 | grahamthreagae@gmail.com
  7 | jsmith       | jsmith@gmail.com
  8 | dierobe      | asdfa@gmail.com
  9 | mike12       | mike@gmail.com
```

And I have a **Friendship** table:

```
 id | user_id | friend_id |  status  
----+---------+-----------+----------
 22 |       6 |         7 | approved
 23 |       6 |         8 | pending
```

I am trying to create a "friend suggester" which suggests friend requesting people you are not friends with. The idea is:

- The current user is logged in with their user ID stored in a session hash.
- That user ID in the session hash should be used to find all the other users that the current user is ***not*** friends with.

The Logic:

- If the current user ID is in the **Friendships** table in the `user_id` column, then exclude that corresponding `friend_id` from being selected.
- Or, if the current user ID is in the **Friendships** table in the `friend_id` column, then exclude that corresponding `user_id` from being selected.

Some queries I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.id
NOT IN (SELECT friendships.user_id FROM friendships)

INTERSECT

SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE users.id
NOT IN (SELECT friendships.friend_id FROM friendships);
```

This one just returns any user that is not in the friendships table, which is not practical, because then `mike12` can't get any friend suggestions. As well, I would think that in a really huge table it would take longer to search such a big record of users instead of just looking for the current user's ID in the friendship table.

---

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM friendships WHERE friendships.user_id = 6
                  OR friendships.friend_id = 6);
```

This one just returns nothing and I am not really sure why to be honest. I have the 6 in their just to test the query.

---

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE 6 NOT IN (SELECT friendships.user_id FROM friendships)

INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE 6 NOT IN (SELECT friendships.friend_id FROM friendships);
```

This one seems to logically make the most sense to me (in my head at least), but also yields no results. I thought this one would return at least the user `mike12` who has an ID of `9`, but it did not.

I know the biggest problem here is that my logic seems to be a little off and I just can't seem to write it out in SQL terms, since I am still relatively new to SQL.

Anyone's knowledge on the matter is deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Remember that on `exists` queries, you make the join to the outer table inside the exists query.  You have no such join in your exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is records in a relation that are **not** represented in some other relation or query result set. That is typically inefficient in SQL. The below works well, but when your tables grow (to millions of records) the performance is not very great and you may have to revise the query. Separate indexes on `friendship.user_id` and `friendship.friend_id` would speed up the query, as well as an index on `user.id`.

The trick is to build a list of id's of the current user and all of his/her friends from the `friendship` table (the sub-query) and then find records in the `users` table that have different id's (the main query):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT 6
  UNION
  SELECT user_id
  FROM friendships
  WHERE friend_id = 6
  UNION
  SELECT friend_id
  FROM friendships
  WHERE user_id = 6)
```

You can wrap this query in a SQL function with a parameter for the current user id such that you can run it for any user id.

Comment: This actually seemed to work very well. I am going to test it out and if it keeps consistently coming back correct like it has been now, I will go ahead and accept this answer. Thank you, great elaboration - it helped me revise my approach.